# Is it possible to set an Expiration Date/Time for a table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if it is possible to set an "Expire" time or date when creating a table in mysql.

For example a table is created and will expire/auto-delete in 2 hours. Something to that effect. Google didn't give any answer so its probably not as simple as I'm hoping.

Need: 
I'm making a site with cart functionality. Users can add items to the cart if they are not signed in. This info is stored in a temp table that will then be migrated to a specific users table or orders once they log in. Well I was trying to find a way to remove the temporary table if say the user never signs in or completes an order and then leaves the site permanently. That way I wouldn't end up with a bunch of temporary tables cluttering things up.

Comment: It just a sql query run every two hour, right?

Comment: This sounds like an error in your schema design. Can you describe your goal to put it in some sort of context? Maybe there's a better way to reach your goal?

Comment: I do this on blog posts and articles. I simply set a created date, store in in the db, then check if the date is `<` the current date. If so, I ignore it

Comment: @EmilVikström I'm making a site with cart functionality. Users can add items to the cart if they are not signed in. This info is stored in a temp table that will then be migrated to a specific users table or orders once they log in. Well I was trying to find a way to remove the temporary table if say the user never signs in or completes an order and then leaves the site permanently.

That way I wouldn't end up with a bunch of temporary tables cluttering things up.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to do that explicitly, but it'd be simple to implement. Just tack on an insertion timestamp to the table's schema (set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on insert), and then have a cronjob or equivalent scheduled job which runs every hour (or however often you deem necessary based on your requirements) that cleans up expired rows (timestamp < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 HOUR)

Comment: @Ryan - store it in a session

Comment: Go for the job! 10 times. Night batches rule!

Comment: @Paul how would I store a table in a session? Or you mean store the added cart items in a session until the user signs in, and then add them to a table...?

Comment: Correct, store the items in a session

Comment: Also, you could store the cart items for all users in the same temp table, and just expire the records with a batch job. However, that sounds a lot like PHP sessions... :)

Comment: Yea I think storing it in a session will be my best approach. Thanks for the inspiration everyone!

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it wrong! It's almost always an error when you change your schema dynamically. You should add and remove rows, not tables.

Put all your orders in the same table and just timestamp them. You can have a field with order status and remove non-completed orders with a `DELETE ... WHERE status='not completed' AND timefield < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)`, or you can put temporary orders in another table than completed orders, but all temp orders should go to the *same* table.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: I'm wondering if it is possible to set an "Expire" time or date
>   when creating a table in mysql.

A: It's easy to set an "added" time or date, then run a batch job to query any/all items older than your "expire" time and take the appropriate action.  Perhaps delete.  Perhaps e-mail a reminder.  Perhaps generate a report and delete - whatever.